# Can I send auditd logs to another computer?

Tags: logs, monitoring, nfs

On a Linux (debian) box, I have a NFS server wich seems to be overloaded by requests. In order to identify the problem, I'm trying to monitor with auditd/auditctl accessed files in the partition exported by the NFS server.

The problem is that our disk or nfs problem prevents auditd to write logs on /var/log/auditd/auditd.log.

What I really need is to send all logs somewhere else than on a local file.

Can I simply redirect all logs from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.2 (the network is working correctly) ?

Comment: Surely, if you use rsyslog as a transport

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on Linux by how you phrased your question.  Should that be the case, then yes there is, look into audisp-remote and audispd.  These are standard components in the current audit tools on Linux.

Comment: I'm using linux, right (just edited my question). I have just found those two tools. Could not find any documentation except man pages yet...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `auditd` log file in `/etc/auditd.conf`. You can't make `auditd` itself send logs over the network, but you can direct it to a file that's on some other remote filesystem such as sshfs.